# Array and Curve modifiers without changing object geometry

Tags: mesh, modifiers, curve-modifier

I have designed a brim for a baseball cap. I want holes in it to sew through. At the end I will use a boolean for the brim to make the holes.

The holes need to have a radius of 0.06 cm and need to be round. Also I want to be able to change the distance between holes, but it needs to be consistent. I also want to easely change the path of where the holes are.
So I decided to use the Array and Curve modifiers.

The problem is that the holes are beging deformed and are no longer round. Also the distance between them is wrong.

I tried doing it with Geometry nodes, but I couldn't get the distance between the nodes the same.

Does someone know how to do this?

[image]

[image]

With the 'parent to ...' method the distance still changes. I wish to use one curvature for multiple rows of holes.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Torus object stretched in array curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier)

Comment: No. I want to use one curvature for multiple arrays. When moving away from the curvature, the distance still changes.

Comment: [This workflow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265481/35559) may suit, if your rim has decent topology

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by using both Modifiers and Geometry Nodes. It is still some manual work, but the distances between lines and holes are easy to change.
[image]

[image]